# docvecs.most_similar() not working properly. Won't find docs

Tags: python

So, I'm new to Python, and this is one of the first problems I'm solving. I realise I'm in over my head a bit, but I really need this done (and I want to learn!).

I'm trying to classify different aricles based on their product description. For this I'm using Gensim Doc2Vec, along with the usual Pandas, Numpy etc.

I have a document of about 6000 unique product descriptions, with their respective article number. I have no difficulty reading the file, formatting and tokenizing it and removing stopwords etc. What is giving me a headache is the acutal model training. To set up the code I'm using a part of the document with only 200 articles, so that the training doesn't take forever each time I get it wrong.

I get results when using the model.most_similar("word") function (although they are not that great, which isn't strange for such a small sample). What bothers me is that I cannot get the model.docvecs.most_similar([doc_id]) function to work.

```
##...Reading and formatting file. Variable 'data' is the df containing tokenized lists etc
.
.
.

def create_taggeddoc (): #Code for creating TaggedDocument-list
    tagged = []
    i = 0
    for row in data['no_stops_nbrs']:
        tag = data['artcle'].iloc[i]
        tagged.append(TaggedDocument(row, tags = tag))
        i += 1

    return tagged


def train_data(): #Returns trained model
    #...training model...
    return model


model.docvecs.most_similar(artnbr) #The one that doesn't work
```

The TaggedDocument method seems correct (albeit unelegant), as:

```
print(tagged[:5])
```

shows the correct wordlists and tags.

For some reason though, the last line doesn't work. When I enter the artnbr parameter as a string: eg

```
model.docvecs.most_similar('1234')
```

I get:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

But when I enter it as an int, eg

```
model.docvecs.most_similar(1234)
```

I get:

KeyError: "doc '1234' not in trained set"

What am I not understanding here?

Sorry if the information is lacking, I'll provide more if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Okay this worked out. Turns out me not making the tags as lists was the problem, even though the TaggedDocments function didn't protest when called.